# Manipulating the DeclaringType of a MethodInfo - Is it possible?

Tags: c#, reflection

Basically, I have a class, let's call it 'Controller', that takes a MethodInfo as a constructor parameter. So, the class that creates this MethodInfo is called 'Descriptor'.  The problem is that when 'Controller' calls the MethodInfo, it always fails with:

```
//MethodInfo creation on Descriptor
var mx = new Func<string>(() => "foo").Method;

//Error caused when Controller runs it
ArgumentException: Method '..anonymous...' declared on type 'Descriptor' cannot be called with instance of type 'Controller'
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateCallInstanceType(Type instanceType, MethodInfo method)
```

The 'Controller' class is completely off limits for me. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have control over code in `Controller` class ?

Comment: Ask the author of `Controller` how the parameter is supposed to be used. From the error message, it seems like `Controller` only wants instance methods of `Controller`. "Manipulating" a `MethodInfo` will not suddenly make a method come from another class, or work with instances that aren't of that class type.

Comment: The code of 'Controller' is from msdn, aspnet core stuff. It basically assumes that the method comes from itself. I guess there is no way then?

Comment: I suspect you're using the class almost, but not entirely, exactly unlike how it's supposed to be used. Is there a way to achieve what you want? Probably. Does it involve calling the constructor of `Controller` with a funky `MethodInfo`? Probably not. There's no way to tell without more context, though. The MVC stack prides itself on being "clean" and extensible, so even stuff that nominally requires tweaking the internals is usually doable without much hacking (though it may require an expert to tell you exactly how).

Comment: In order to invoke a `MethodInfo` you also need an instance of the class in which `MethodInfo` resides unless it's a static method. If you want to pass a method that can be invoked, I'd use `Func<string>` instead of passing a `MethodInfo`.

Comment: The `Controller` class is receiving the `MethodInfo` but when it calls it, it fails. The trouble is that the problem is primarily inside the `Controller` class, which is the part you can't change. Unfortunately, someone has done something evil that you're stuck with. What is the code in the `Controller` class that invokes the `MethodInfo`? Perhaps we can modify the way the `MethodInfo` is created to accommodate the evil you can't change in `Controller`.

Comment: I think I see the answer in the error. The controller is trying to invoke the `MethodInfo` on itself, as if it is a member of the same class. If that's the case, and you can't change it, then the only way this can work is if the method passed is a member of the `Controller` class. There's really no other way. It's mind-boggling that someone would do this. You have my sympathy.